# How to solve "All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification" issue?

Tags: android, gradle, anko

Specifically, how to solve the issue if the plugin that has the problem is already the latest?

I'm new to Android programming, and definitely new to Gradle concept. This issue arises after I followed some tutorial on the internet that instructs to add new dependencies into the main app.

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0, 27.1.1. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and
>   com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1

But I don't have stated dependency that says "support-media-compat:27.1.1". So I figured this must be one of the plugin I use. The problem is, how am I supposed to know which plugin causes this?

After a lengthy googling and getting tons of red herrings, I found out that you can straight up expands the dependency tree using gradle command in the console:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

Which then led me found this:

```
+--- org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.8
....
|    +--- org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:0.10.8
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.0 -> 1.3.21 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 -> 28.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support-v4:0.10.8
|    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.0 -> 1.3.21 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 -> 28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1    <-----
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1 -> 28.0.0
|    |    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 -> 28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 -> 28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 -> 28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1 -> 28.0.0 (*)
....
```

Now I know that it's because `anko:0.10.8`. I did remember that this issue started to arise after I added the anko plugin. From answers I read earlier, usually the solution is to use the latest version of the plugin. But when I see [the plugin version](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/releases), the latest is already `0.10.8`. So I'm confused about what to do next.

This is my dependencies by the way:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.StevenDXC:DxLoadingButton:2.2'

    implementation 'com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.3'

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0"

    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have also tried the solution to downgrade the `appcompat` to `27.1.1` instead, and that requires me to also downgrade the android compileSdkVersion to 27. But even after change all that, that leads to even more version incompatibility with other plugins.

How can I resolve this, and still using `anko` plugins?

Comment: exclude that dependency

Comment: @VivekMishra what made me wonder is this anko plugin is supposedly a popular plugin. I will expect many people will have problem with this. But as I search on the internet, I rarely see similar situation as mine. So I figure that maybe there's solution to fix this rather than just straight up excluding the anko. The weird thing is, *sometimes* I can compile the app, and *sometimes* I can't. So it's not consistently making the compile fail, so I think this issue is actually can be bypassed. But I don't know how to consistently bypass it or workaround it.

Comment: I am not saying to exclude anko. Only exclude the support library version from anko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the conflicting dependencies with the latest version in your `app/build.gradle`.

So, if it tell you that some library is using `com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1`, then you need to add that dependency in your `app/build.gradle` with the latest version that you're using, i.e. in your case, `com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0`

Keep doing this, until all the dependencies in your app are using the latest version.

Comment: Oh, yea, this is finally the answer that works wonders for me!

Comment: You'll receive that popup a lot of times. You can either choose to completely ignore it using lint commands which ignore that error completely(you need to do that if keeping that library is of utmost importance to you). Or you can do this and upgrade the library completely

Comment: Yea, in the end, I end up just adding `support-media-compat` and `support-v4`, and the issue is completely gone. 

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, you should add the dependencies that is told you in error text ,,
for example for your case add:

implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'

AND

implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'

and sync your gradle

Comment: Well, the error is still there. BUT it finally compiles. So I would say this solves the issue. I have no problem as long as it compiles and produces no crash.

Comment: oh, i'm sorry dear , you should add the dependencies that is told you in error text,But you must change the version of them, these version must the same with version of support library

Answer (score 0):

This issue is raised bdue to **org.jetbrains.anko:anko** you have used. It contains full bundle setup. Instead you need to avoid usage of bundle version of SDK. Instead use only needed feature.

If you just want to use anko for SQLite management then use only below dependency.

```
// Anko SQLite
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sqlite:$anko_version"
```

So instead of using that full bundled sdk please use sdk with only needed features from below.

```
dependencies {
    // Anko Commons
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"

    // Anko Layouts (These are the dependencies which causing the issue.)
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk25:$anko_version" // sdk15, sdk19, sdk21, sdk23 are also available
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version"

    // Coroutine listeners for Anko Layouts
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk25-coroutines:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7-coroutines:$anko_version"

    // Anko SQLite
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sqlite:$anko_version"
}
```

Refer full documentation [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko#using-anko).

Comment: This is a great answer, and probably should be the accepted answer. But this probably requires a full understanding about what is inside anko, and as a new android developer, it didn't even occur to me that you can install parts of anko, or where to find documentation of what parts of anko I can install a la carte. But thank you for the knowledge that way like this exists.

Comment: @ChenLiYong I'm having same issue while using Anko lib. And I solved out using this answer. I need to use only library which I really need. I think this should be accepted answer.

Comment: @TheMask I agree. But the answer that I actually can implement is the accepted answer, because this answer is way too complicated for me, as right now with my skill, I still have no way to know which library I really need. From a beginner perspective, the implementable solution with limited knowledge is the accepted answer.